# How do you write something in a specific line in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Multi threaded script, in which every thread should output information on a specific line. The first thread prints in the first line, the second threat writes on the second line, etc. But How can one print on a specific line?

Comment: A line of what? Console? File? GUI?

Comment: Would it solve your problem if you knew how to arrange the thread results in a list whose order was the desired order of the information? Since the list has the proper order, you can just print each item of the list to a separate line.

Answer (score 0):

That depends whether you're in a console or in a graphical interface, and furthermore what platform you're on.

This task is (arguably) easier in a graphical interface, like `tkinter` which is included with Python. These interfaces work across all platforms.

If you're on non-Windows platform you can use `curses` for a console based interface: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html

If you're on Windows and you want console interface you can use something like `windows-curses` which attempts to provide similar console interfaces: https://pypi.org/project/windows-curses/